# Where to store data read from config

Tags: c#

I have stored static values in an app.config file which are to be used throughout a project. I store usernames, passwords, url locations, etc.

Is it better to create a global public static list of variables which can be accessed anywhere in the project or do I need to create new variables and retrieve the configuration data each time I need it?

Comment: This can't be answered without seeing some code. Usually you want to read the configuration in one place, then pass the relevant values to the appropriate class constructors.

Comment: This is a very open ended question and totally driven by requirements and design. I would personally not prefer storing sensitive information like passwords in plain text in config file.

Comment: I think this will be too opinion based. It's all situationally dependent. If it's only a few values, then access them each time, if it's a lot of values construct a class to read and hold them all and pass that along. You're gonna end up with a different answer depending on who answers.

Answer (score -1):

You can retrive the value of your application settings just by calling

`ProjectName.Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName`

Providing these values don't need to be changed, there is no need to assign them to any static varible.

More information [Using Settings in C# MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx)